# import statement crashing an angular app despite installed module

Tags: angular, typescript, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

What could be the reason that an `import` statement would cause an error (attached image) if the syntax is correct and the library has already been installed? **Could it be something in the two main settings files below (*package.json* & *tsconfig.json*)?**

We have inherited a big Angular application, and have installed in it `vega` & `vega-lite` & `vega-embed` using `npm` and now we are trying to embed vega graphs in the local-server webpage that is served.

The contents of the main files are as follows:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "a-chis-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "d3": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "vega": "^5.20.2",
    "vega-embed": "^6.18.2",
    "vega-lite": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

*vega.component.html*

```
<h3 class="center">Vega Viz</h3>

<figure id="vega" class="center"></figure>
```

*vega.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import embed from 'vega-embed';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vega',
  templateUrl: './vega.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vega.component.css']
})
export class VegaComponent implements OnInit {

  svg: any;

  margin = 50;
  width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    this.embedGraph();
  }

  createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3
      .select("figure#vega")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width + (this.margin * 2))
      .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 2))
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
  }

  async embedGraph(): Promise<void> {
    const spec = "/assets/density-heatmaps.vg.json";
    embed.vegaEmbed("figure#vega", spec);
    const result = await embed("figure#vega", spec);
    console.log(result.view);
  }
}
```

We have tried all the following:

```
import { default as vegaEmbed } from 'vega-embed';
import * as embed from 'vega-embed';
import embed from 'vega-embed';
var embed = require("vega-embed");
var vega = require('vega');
require('vega-embed');
```

They all crash the app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you expand error messages?

Comment: @Dmitry Grinko Done! Added a screenshot of the collapsed errors. I hope you can help... Please let me know if you need more info to diagnose the issue. Thanks

Comment: I fixed our issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722781/importing-vega-embed-after-installation/68738716#68738716)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved an identical problem by adding `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to our `tsconfig.json` file:.

The complete file now looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

[This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) page prompted the solution.